# Passing an array to the method.

Tags: c#

I have written a simple code and have passed an array to the method and have returned the value and trying to get it printed. Somehow, I am not getting the required output. Please point out where I got wrong. Also tips to make the code concise are most welcome.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ar = new string[] { "hello", "world", "people" };

        writeString(ar);
        Console.WriteLine(ar);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static string writeString(string[] ar)
    {
        string a1 = " ";
        foreach (string a in ar)
        {
            a1 = a1 + a;
        }
        return a1;
    }
```

Comment: You are not catching `writeString`s return

Comment: @LPK - while completely correct, I think you misunderstood OP's intention -   clearly `writeString` should write string - meaning it should be  writing to console instead of returning result...

Comment: Use the Value returned by the method `writeString`

Comment: ```Console.WriteLine(writestring(ar));```

Comment: Do consider String.Join suggested by multiple answers, if you are trying to convert whole array into single string separated by a delimiter, though your question doesn't suggest that as a requirement.

Comment: Thanks @MrinalKamboj, LPK, Alexei, GauravKP and tym32167!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the code sample makes it clear. You have to capture the return value from the writeString function and output that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] ar = new string[] { "hello", "world", "people" };

    string output = writeString(ar);
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

static string writeString(string[] ar)
{
    string a1 = " ";
    foreach (string a in ar)
    {
        a1 = a1 + a;
    }
    return a1;
}
```

Comment: Additionally String.Join() can be used to replace the writeString() function with a few adjustments.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years In original question OP is not replicating Join functionality, since Join will add limiter post all the elements of the collection, as it creates a single string, here empty space is only appended i nthe beginning, not between elements

Comment: @MrinalKamboj What if I do output=" "+String.Join(String.Empty,ar); ? Would something like this work? I don't know i haven't code C# for like 3 years.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years would certainly, in fact that's what he's trying to do in current method, however, my gut feeling is OP might actually need a Join, that you have showed earlier :)

Comment: @SaurabhCooks I'm glad. Could you accept it is the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can `refactor` it as below with concise code without the need of another method.

Note: I have added space before the array items as you did. But if you need space between each items of array then change the `delimiter` line as `string delimiter = " ";`

You can change the `delimiter` below with any character like `,` etc.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] ar = new string[] { "hello", "world", "people" };

    string delimiter = "";
    string output = " " + String.Join(delimiter, ar);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    // You can do the same in one line as below by commenting above three lines
    // Console.WriteLine(" " + String.Join("", ar));

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Original functionality doesn't do the work of  `Join`, eve if that's the intention as it just adds the empty space in the beginning and no where else

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Why not add the same here with `" " + String.Join(delimitter, ar)` ?

Comment: I think, he needs space between the array items and doing wrongly. In that case `delimitter` becomes `string delimitter = " ";`

Comment: That's your assumption of what OP needs, it is not specified anywhere, so I am not sure, what's the use case, he just asked about printing output, which was anyway wrong.

Comment: Please read his question once again. He asks for `Also tips to make the code concise are most welcome`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a space in the front. Check the output of both and please come here if anything different :-)

Comment: Yes that match the current use case, Kudos, though actually OP might actually just need your original code :)

Comment: Yes, I guess he is trying to add a space between each item. Anyways I have mentioned the same in the note

Comment: @Aruna, thanks to you for the wonderful tip on using("Join").

Comment: @Aruna can you plz advice me abt. a book which could help me gain knowledge on framework libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the string returned by the `writeString(string[] ar)` method. Instead you are printing the input string array variable `ar` (on line `Console.WriteLine(ar)`). That's your problem. That `WriteLine` statement prints only the fully qualified name of the variable `ar`'s type: `System.String[]`.

Change the line `Console.WriteLine(ar)` to `Console.WriteLine(writeString(ar))` to get your desired output.

Comment: Please add some code to make it a valid answer or better use comment section for a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> I have written a simple code and have passed an array to the method and have returned the value and trying to get it printed. Somehow, I am not getting the required output

As everyone has pointed that you are not receiving the returned value to print it or do anything with it, so a simple code modification is first receive the result / output:

```
var result =  writeString(ar);
```

> What is your Result expectation

Since you are printing the array, instead of returned value. Array is not even modified in the called function anywhere, therefore it remains exactly same. Simplest way to achieve the expected result would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(writeString(ar));
```